# Pascal's Triangle - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I've already created a program that will display x number of rows and repeat that :

i.e.

```
1
2 2
3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6 6
```

Now I want to make Pascal's Triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
Dim arr As Integer(,) = New Integer(7, 7) {}
 For i As Integer = 0 To 7
    For k As Integer = 7 To i + 1 Step -1
        'print spaces
        Console.Write(" ")
    Next

    For j As Integer = 0 To i - 1
        If j = 0 OrElse i = j Then
            arr(i, j) = 1
        Else
            arr(i, j) = arr(i - 1, j) + arr(i - 1, j - 1)
        End If
        Console.Write(arr(i, j) & " ")
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

Console-output:

[image]

Comment: Ok I got this to work in a console application, however I want to make it in a Form style where the user inputs the row number. I'm self-learning VB right now therefore I'm trying to understand this example.. Could you provide a small explanantion to how it's working? thanks a lot !

Comment: I added some new code above that I understand better if you could take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, only keeps previous and current iterations in memory:

```
Dim oldList As New List(Of Integer)({0, 1})
For line = 1 To 7
  Dim newList As New List(Of Integer)
  For i = 1 To oldList.Count - 1
    newList.Add(oldList(i - 1) + oldList(i))
  Next
  Debug.Print(String.Join(" ", newList))
  oldList.Clear()
  oldList.Add(0)
  oldList.AddRange(newList)
  oldList.Add(0)
Next
```

Comment: How would I output this to a Label and also how could I make the number of rows variable to be input by the user?

Comment: I added some new code above that I understand better if you could take a look. Thanks

Comment: @DavidSalib: regarding output to label, collect into StringBuilder first, then dump it to your label, like this `Label.Text = sb.ToString()`. So you would replace `Debug.Print(String.Join(" ", newList))` with `sb.AppendLine(String.Join(" ", newList))`. 7 is a number of rows to be calculated, replace that with CInt(yourInput.Text) and don't forget about error checking.

Answer (score 0):

to  do that using a windows form, you would need a textbox,multi-line textbox and a button on the design interface

here is the code you need to generate it

```
Imports System.Numerics 'this allows you to  use big integer

Public Class pascal_triangle


    Private Function factorial(ByVal k As Integer) As BigInteger

'big integer allows your proram compute for inputs of more than 22

        If k = 0 Or k = 1 Then

            Return 1

        Else

            Return k * factorial(k - 1)


        End If

    End Function



    Private Sub BtnGen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnGen.Click
        Dim nCr As Double

        Dim i, j, k As Integer


        Dim output As String

        output = ""

        j = Val(TxtColumn.Text)

        For k = 0 To j

            For i = 0 To k

                Dim fact, fact1, fact2 As BigInteger



                fact = factorial(k)

                fact1 = factorial(k - i)

                fact2 = factorial(i)

                nCr = fact / (fact1 * fact2)

                TxtOutput.Text += Str(nCr) & output





            Next

            TxtOutput.Text += vbCrLf

        Next



    End Sub


    Private Sub pascal_triangle_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```